# How to execute the eval function with a modified window object

Tags: javascript, iframe, eval

I make a call to `eval` in my code, and I have a reference to an `iframe`'s window object. Is there any way to execute eval (or something that achieves the same) but have the window object set to the `iframe.contentWindow` for all code executed by eval. I need to retain access to the window in the rest of the code.

Comment: Just use `iframe.contentWindow.eval()`?

Comment: Is eval a method on window?

Comment: @Bergi I checked and it works. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the normal `eval`, but the `eval` function from the iframe's realm:

```
iframe.contentWindow.eval(…)
```

Notice that this runs the code in the global scope of the iframe, not in the current scope. And all literals will create instances of the respective `Object`, `Array`, `RegExp` objects from the iframe realm as well, which might cause some annoyances.